# unexpected '=', expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error: "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting kEND".  The error traces back to the first instance of "=" in a partial:

```
<hr class="featurette-divider">
<a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" onclick="location.href=nextUrl;return false">More Lunar Science Facts ></a>
<hr class="featurette-divider">
```

The route for the partial is app/views/layouts/_next.html.erb.

The partial is called in the view, here:

```
<article>
<div id="container">
    <br/>
    <div class="img-polaroid pull-right">
        <%= image_tag("IMG/twelveB.png") %>
    </div>
    <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </header>
    <p>
        ...content...
    </p>
    <%= render 'layouts/next' %>
    For printable version: <a href="DOCS/card12.pdf">Click Here</a>
</article>
```

Comment: What's before that first block of code that you posted? There may be some ERB that's not closed properly.

Comment: That first block of code is the entire contents of the file (app/views/layouts/_next.html.erb)

Comment: So, get this: if I create another file (app/views/layouts/_next.html.erb) with the exact same contents (I vimdiff'd to make sure of it), I no longer get the error.  Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have forgotten to close an ERb `<% %>` tag pair. This HTML is being interpreted as Ruby.

Comment: I double checked all of my tags in the view and the partial, all of my  `<%=` have a `%>`